# Looking for a web site that displays list of specific dates that Jewish holidays occurred

Tags: calendar, technology, statistics

I am looking for a web site that can shows some statistics such as the last time that the 1st day of Chanukah was on Friday, or even a list of when such occurrences were in the past several centuries, or when it will next occur. I could scroll through a sequence of annual calendars, or look at a *kevi'ot* table, but this would be a somewhat tedious process.

Is there a web site that can provide a quick calculation?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this site](https://www.stevemorse.org/jcal/whendid.html). Not only does it answer my questions, above, but it also coordinates Gregorian and Hebrew calendars, so you can find out when the last time Rosh Hashanna and Labor Day coincided, and similar questions.

For many cases, you have to know the Hebrew date of a Jewish holiday. That is provided on the side bar of the web page.

Comment: Superb find! Very useful

Comment: @Oliver Thanks. Steve Morse, the site designer has compiled an interesting overall site with very useful concise info on how the Jewish calendar works. His summary of when the 1st day of Rosh Hashanna occurs with its 4 postponement rules is, probably, the best written summary I've seen, anywhere. It's well worth browsing around his site.

Answer (score 0):

There is something called "[Kaluach](http://www.aish.com/jl/hol/o/48970511.html)" from Aish which might be of help or their [interactive calendar](http://www.aish.com/jewish-calendar/?s=bc) which has the history of that day and other useful information.